# How to blur stage

Tags: actionscript-3

Is there any way to blur all stage.
This code is not working.

```
stage.filters = [(new BlurFilter())];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The stage object does not support the use of filters.
Wrap everything in a main container instead and set the blur on it.

Ref >>
http://wadhwakanu.wordpress.com/2011/01/16/error-2071-the-stage-class-does-not-implement-this-property-or-method/

Answer (score 1):

Let have stage only a single child and add all other children to this one. Also apply the filter to this one. Commonly you have set a `Document Class` or `Main Class` (AS3 only projects) which extends from `Sprite` or `MovieClip`. Apply the filter to the instance of this class which is automatically created.